# UITableViewCell's not appearing at all

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My `UITableViewCell`'s are not appearing.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return resultsProdName.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: tvcMyProducts = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tblViewCellMyProdsss", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tvcMyProducts

    if self.resultsProdsDescArray.count > 0 && self.resultsProdName.count > 0 {
        cell.lblProdDesc.text = self.resultsProdsDescArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblProdName.text = self.resultsProdName[indexPath.row]
        if (self.resultsHasProdPicArray[indexPath.row] != false) {
            resultsProdPicArray[indexPath.row]?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imgData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    cell.imgViewProdPic.image = UIImage(data: imgData!)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have made the super class conform to: `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

I've done everything I have searched for, yet it is still not appearing. The `UITableViewCell` even has a unique identifier that I call in the code: `tblViewCellMyProdsss`

And the class `tvcMyProducts` is a `UITableViewCell` which contains the `imgViewProdPic` & `lblProdName` etc.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

The `UITableViewCell`'s aren't even appearing when I run the program with their "stock data" that I have entered. It is not appearing at all.

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug! See if the code is even running. If it is, look at the values as it steps from line to line. Solve it yourself. For example, if `resultsProdName.count` were zero, you'd get no cells. There are lots of possible reasons. Figure it out!

Comment: super simple ways to "debug": [breakpoints](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode), or add `print(someValue)`  in places you are not sure about the state of your function.

Comment: Make sure to set the delegates of the tableView.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And I fixed it myself. All I had to add was: `self.tblViewMyProds.reloadData()` after I called my functions.